# issues running php as it unable to find the file

Tags: php

I am using the following to run the php file under xampp htdocs with foldername as kraken but i am getting an error

```
<?php

require_once 'KrakenAPIClient.php'; 

$key = 'dfdfdfdf';
$secret = 'dfdfdfdf';

// set which platform to use (currently only beta is operational, live available soon)
$beta = false; 
$url = $beta ? 'https://api.beta.kraken.com' : 'https://api.kraken.com';
$sslverify = $beta ? false : true;
$version = 0;

$kraken = new KrakenAPI($key, $secret, $url, $version, $sslverify);
```

error i am getting is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'KrakenAPI' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\kraken\example.php:21 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\kraken\example.php on line 21
```

Comment: If [this is the API you're referring to](https://github.com/krakenfx/kraken-api-client/blob/master/php/KrakenAPIClient.php), you need to [import the class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) first, or use the fully qualified name of the class (`\Payward\KrakenAPI`).

Comment: `use \Payward\KrakenAPI;` should also work.

Comment: post as an answer,

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to alias the class with [`use`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php), before being able to skip it's name-space:

```
use \Payward\KrakenAPI;
```

Also see the PHP manual which I've linked for a more detailed explanation.